# Trouble updating Apache - mod_deflate APR_INT32_MAX undeclared

Tags: apache-httpd, compiling, apr

I am currently trying to upgrade apache from 2.2.8 to 2.2.29 and am running into some trouble.

I configured the makefile like so:

```
./configure --enable-mods-shared --enable-ssl --enable-rewrite --enable-proxy-ftp --enable-proxy-http --enable-proxy-connect --enable-proxy --enable-cache --enable-mem-cache --enable-expires --enable-hea
ders --enable-deflateloca --enable-unique-id
```

When running the make command I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/apache2/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -g -O2 -pthread    -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE    -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/srclib/pcre -I. -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/os/unix -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/server/mpm/prefork -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/http -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/filters -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/proxy -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/include -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/generators -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/mappers -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/database -I/usr/local/apache2/include -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/proxy/../generators -I/usr/kerberos/include -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/ssl -I/opt/vignette/software/apache/modules/dav/main  -prefer-non-pic -static -c mod_deflate.c && touch mod_deflate.lo
mod_deflate.c: In function `deflate_out_filter':
mod_deflate.c:790: error: `APR_INT32_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_deflate.c:790: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
mod_deflate.c:790: error: for each function it appears in.)
mod_deflate.c: In function `deflate_in_filter':
mod_deflate.c:1165: error: `APR_INT32_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_deflate.c: In function `inflate_out_filter':
mod_deflate.c:1550: error: `APR_INT32_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[3]: *** [mod_deflate.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/vignette/software/httpd-2.2.29/modules/filters'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/vignette/software/httpd-2.2.29/modules/filters'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/vignette/software/httpd-2.2.29/modules'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Now when I go to line 790 of deflate.c it has this:

```
 if (len > APR_INT32_MAX) {
            apr_bucket_split(e, APR_INT32_MAX);
            apr_bucket_read(e, &data, &len, APR_BLOCK_READ);
        }
```

For some reason I don't think this variable is getting set for whatever reason.

I will note that I am running RHEL4 (I know it's bad) and that I just recently installed APR (Apache Runtime) and APU (Apache Runtime Utility) and have them configured in:

```
/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config
/usr/local/apr/bin/apu-1-config
```

I am not sure if these are related or if it's causing a problem since I installed APR independently and the fact that it comes with apache. The reason I have them installed separately is because another program I have installed is dependent on a different version.

I will say that when I configure the makefile without deflate the binary compiles successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of trying to figure this out here is the solution.

There seemed to be an old APR library (< v1.3.0) installed on the system that was in conflict with the version needed for apache. What I did was compile (and run) with the APR embedded in the httpd-2.2.29 archive using: ./configure --with-included-apr